# Run linux command from web page

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to run command from a web page (php) to my linux server. My php page look like this: `$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/var/www');
$output = shell_exec('./test.pl');
chdir($old_path);`

test.pl is a simple test file that create a txt file. 
If I run the command `php /var/www/page.php` everything works fine, but when I request the page in the browser nothing happen.

Thanks !

Comment: often this is a permission issue, the file is run as what ever php is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Make the owner of the file the apache/php user `www-data:www-data`

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/test.pl
```

Give the group and others the right to execute it

```
chmod go+x /var/www/test.pl
```

Then put the absolut path into shell exec

```
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/test.pl');
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Done, I get: NULL on the page, but the file don't run

Comment: @user3534084 just edited my answer with file permission change can you try and tell me if it work's ?

Comment: @user3534084 for testing purpose could you chmod 777 /var/www/test.pl and try again you're script ?

Comment: You mean only run chmod 777 /var/www/test.pl and request de script or run chmod 777 /var/www/test.pl and rerun what you said in your post ? I did the first thing (run chmod and request) but it still don't work

Comment: Ok it's apparenty not a permissions problem now try to run `$output = shell_exec('cat /var/www/test.pl');
var_dump($output); ` and tell me if it outpout the file content ?

Comment: I get: string(19) "sudo touch test.txt "

Comment: do you have any other idea of what I could do ?